# What is default color of TextBlock.Foreground?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is default value of TextBlock's Foreground one of the SystemColors? If so, which one is it?

Comment: Should be SystemColors.WindowText, black by default.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but there is no such property in System.Windows.SystemColors. I tried to set all four properties, that starts with WindowText, but none of them work

Comment: You cannot set SystemColors properties, only the user can change them.  She controls the machine, not you.

Comment: You can override resource - [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2007/03/25/109753.aspx)

Comment: I made some changes to my answer as there were some inaccuracies and errors stemming from a fallacy on my part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is rather theme-dependent, if there is no override from the applying theme the DP-system uses the default value of the respective `DependencyProperty`, which is `Brushes.Black`.

There are however many possibly overrides, in the Aero theme inheritance changes the value in some cases. While the `TextBlock` style does not set the `Foreground` directly (which would be a stronger override), the `Foreground` of `Windows` is set to `{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}` so if the `TextBlock` is in a `Window` the brush associated with that key will be applied unless the inheritance is overridden by another value of even higher [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

```
Foreground="{ThemeResource DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Textblock's foreground hex value is `#FF000000`